# Can all __future__ statements be removed from python code, without affecting its functionality using python 3.7.1?

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, python-import

Can the following `__future__` statements be removed from source code, without affecting its functionality if I am using python 3.7.1?

```
from __future__ import nested_scopes
from __future__ import generators
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import with_statement
from __future__ import print_function
from __future__ import unicode_literals
```

Comment: "All" and "these particular" are… different. There are other futures in 3.7 which *do* change behaviour: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0563/#enabling-the-future-behavior-in-python-3-7

Comment: Yes you are correct. I wish I could edit the title of the question :(

Comment: Well… you [*can*](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53830960/edit).

Comment: Thanks! @deceze but I think it is too late to edit the title because people have already answered according to this title.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is documented in the [`lib/python3.7/__future__.py`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/__future__.py) file. Each future import (here called `_Feature`) is given two 5-tuples, specifying optional and mandatory releases, respectively. Here, "mandatory release" means which version of Python includes the feature by default. As you can see by following the link above, all mandatory versions are < 3.7.1 except two, namely [`barry_as_FLUFL`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0401/) (mandatory in version 3.9.0) and [`annotations`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0563/) (mandatory in version 4.0.0), the first of which is just an Easter egg.

All future imports on your list can then indeed be removed if using Python 3.7.1 or newer, with the exact same code execution guaranteed. As others have commented, this might not be a good idea though, as this reduces code compatibility.

Comment: I think that's clear it up. Thanks for your informative reply

Comment: good find, +1, but `barry_as_FLUFL` surely won't become mandatory in 3.9 and the default, otherwise it would break the `!=` operator!

Comment: @jmd_dk That would be taking the joke too far! I added a short script to my answer based on your suggestion to look at the `__future__` module itself, i hope you don't mind

Answer (score 3):

You could remove *those* `__future__` imports without impacting functionality, but removing them is not necessary and stops compatibility with earlier python versions.

Moreover, as @deceze alludes to in his comment, *other* imports may be different. For example, `from __future__ import annotations` is [only *enabled*](https://docs.python.org/dev/whatsnew/3.7.html) in Python <= 4.0 via the import, so adding/removing that line would impact the functionality:

> Since this change breaks compatibility, the new behavior needs to be
>   enabled on a per-module basis in Python 3.7 using a `__future__` import:
>
> `from __future__ import annotations`
>
> It will become the default in Python 4.0.

As @jmd_dk points out, you can actually find this information in the `__future__` module. I wrote a short script to extract it:

```
import __future__
import ast
import sys

print('Python version:', sys.version_info)

sys_t = sys.version_info[:3]

s = '__future__ import {} {} for you; the version: {} vs. your version: {}'

for name in __future__.all_feature_names:
    optional, mandatory, _ = ast.literal_eval(str(getattr(__future__, name)).lstrip('_Featur'))
    optional, mandatory = optional[:3], mandatory[:3]
    print('\nName: {}'.format(name))
    tmp = [None, None, optional, sys_t]
    if optional <= sys_t:
        tmp[:2] = 'is', 'included'
    else:
        tmp[:2] = 'not', 'included'
    print(s.format(*tmp))
    tmp[2] = mandatory
    if mandatory <= sys_t:
        tmp[:2] = 'is', 'fixed'
    else:
        tmp[:2] = 'not', 'fixed'
    print(s.format(*tmp))
```

On my system this outputs:

```
Python version: sys.version_info(major=3, minor=7, micro=1, releaselevel='final', serial=0)

Name: nested_scopes
__future__ import is included for you; the version: (2, 1, 0) vs. your version: (3, 7, 1)
__future__ import is fixed for you; the version: (2, 2, 0) vs. your version: (3, 7, 1)

Name: generators
__future__ import is included for you; the version: (2, 2, 0) vs. your version: (3, 7, 1)
__future__ import is fixed for you; the version: (2, 3, 0) vs. your version: (3, 7, 1)

Name: division
__future__ import is included for you; the version: (2, 2, 0) vs. your version: (3, 7, 1)
__future__ import is fixed for you; the version: (3, 0, 0) vs. your version: (3, 7, 1)

Name: absolute_import
__future__ import is included for you; the version: (2, 5, 0) vs. your version: (3, 7, 1)
__future__ import is fixed for you; the version: (3, 0, 0) vs. your version: (3, 7, 1)

Name: with_statement
__future__ import is included for you; the version: (2, 5, 0) vs. your version: (3, 7, 1)
__future__ import is fixed for you; the version: (2, 6, 0) vs. your version: (3, 7, 1)

Name: print_function
__future__ import is included for you; the version: (2, 6, 0) vs. your version: (3, 7, 1)
__future__ import is fixed for you; the version: (3, 0, 0) vs. your version: (3, 7, 1)

Name: unicode_literals
__future__ import is included for you; the version: (2, 6, 0) vs. your version: (3, 7, 1)
__future__ import is fixed for you; the version: (3, 0, 0) vs. your version: (3, 7, 1)

Name: barry_as_FLUFL
__future__ import is included for you; the version: (3, 1, 0) vs. your version: (3, 7, 1)
__future__ import not fixed for you; the version: (3, 9, 0) vs. your version: (3, 7, 1)

Name: generator_stop
__future__ import is included for you; the version: (3, 5, 0) vs. your version: (3, 7, 1)
__future__ import is fixed for you; the version: (3, 7, 0) vs. your version: (3, 7, 1)

Name: annotations
__future__ import is included for you; the version: (3, 7, 0) vs. your version: (3, 7, 1)
__future__ import not fixed for you; the version: (4, 0, 0) vs. your version: (3, 7, 1)
```

When Python >= 3.8 introduces `__future__` imports (there are none yet as I write this), removing *these* and running on Python 3.7 obviously would impact the functionality.

Comment: Thanks! @Chris_Rands